# Python library for calculating physical and chemical properties of materials

Tags: python

I've been trying to find a viable replacement for EES (Engineer Equation Solver) that uses only FOSS. Right now I'm wondering if there is an easy way to figure out important physical properties of materials using Python, instead of having to spend lots of times searching the internet.

EES allows us to do something like:

> ## Calculate the Prandtl number of Water at 300 K and 1 atm
>
> prandtl_water = Prandtl('Water', '300 K', '1 atm')

-

> ## Calculate the specific heat of air at 1 atm and 300 K
>
> c_p_air = Cp('Air', '1 atm', '300 K')

-

> ## Calculate aluminium tensile strength
>
> sigma_max_aluminium = UTS('Aluminium')  #UTS as in ultimate tensile stength

-

You get the idea. Is there something of the sort in Python, or another FOSS software? I tried searching around the internet, but couldn't find anything similar to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, found what I was looking for in this reddit thread; and plenty of solutions as well:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/5iorju/library_for_thermodynamic_and_fluid_properties/

Here's a list:

[Cantera](https://cantera.org/documentation/docs-2.3/sphinx/html/index.html)

[thermo](https://github.com/CalebBell/thermo)

[iapws](https://pypi.org/project/iapws/1.1.3/) - For water